# Subtract two strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring, trim, substr

kwd variable holds this value:  **news path:".aspx"**
It is basically the query string of an url.

```
  var path= "path:\".aspx\"";
```

so kwd=  whatever user types passed to the url like this+path:

```
kwd=news path:".aspx";
```

I need to subtract kwd-path so i get only "news"
How do i do that in java-script or jquery?

I know i can either use trim or substring or substr..
But I couldn't get to work .
I am basically using this logic:

```
if (b.startsWith(a)) {
        return b.subString(a.length());
    }

    if (b.endsWith(a)) {
        return b.subString(0, b.length() - a.length());
    }
```

But this is not working..

```
 var persistvalue= kwd.subString(0, kwd.length() - path.length());
```

Comment: Can you simply replace with empty string?  'b.replace(a, '');'

Answer (score 0):

`kwd.length() - path.length()` - isn't this value negative?

try `path.length() - kwd.length()`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `.aspx` is inside a string, you must first extract it from the string:

```
>>> 'an example:"some text"'.match(/"(.*)"/)[1]
"some text"
```

Now you can remove a string if it appears at the end:

```
function removeFromEnd(string, toRemove) {
    function literally(regexp) {
        regexp.replace(/./g, function(x){return '\\'+x})
    }
    yourString.replace(RegExp(literally(string)+'$'), '')
}
```

The `$` means the end-of-string. Alternatively you can do it much more simply with:

```
function removeFromEnd(string, toRemove) {
    if (string.slice(-toRemove.length)==toRemove)
        return string.slice(0, -toRemove.length);
    else
        return string
}
```